# Confusion with foreach in php

Tags: php, foreach

I having some trouble with a loop in php. It's with the foreach loop. I have this code:

```
<?php foreach($obras as $obra): ?>
    <li>
        <a class="thumb" href="<?php echo $base_url . 'assets/uploads/files/' . $obra["imagen"] ?>" title="<?php echo $obra['titulo'] ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $base_url . 'assets/uploads/files/' . $obra["imagen"] ?>" alt="<?php echo $obra['titulo'] ?>" />
        </a>
        <div class="caption">
            <div class="image-desc">

                <p><?= t('global_pieces_artist')?>: <?php echo $obra['nombre_artista'] . ' ' . $obra['apellidos_artista'] ?></p>
                <p><?= t('global_pieces_title')?>: <?php echo $obra['titulo'] ?></p>
                <p><?= t('global_pieces_year')?>: <?php echo $obra['ano'] ?></p>
                <p><?= t('global_pieces_size')?> (cm.): <?php echo $obra['tamano_alto'] ?> x <?php echo $obra['tamano_ancho'] ?><? if ($obra['tamano_largo'] != null): ?> x <?php echo $obra['tamano_largo'] ?><? endif; ?></p>
                <p><?= t('global_pieces_technique')?>: <?php echo $obra['tecnica'] ?> </p>

                <? if (isset($obra['username'])): ?>
                    <p><?= t('global_company') ?>: <?php= echo $obra['username'] ?></p>
                <? endif; ?>

                <p><?= t('global_pieces_price')?>: <?php echo ($obra['precio'] . ' ' . $obra['divisa']) ?> (<?= t('global_pieces_price_vat')?>)</p>

                <? if ($obra['observaciones'] != null): ?>
                    <p><?= t('global_pieces_observations')?>: <?php echo $obra['observaciones'] ?></p>
                <? endif; ?>

                <p id="links_last">
                    <a href="<?php echo $base_url . 'assets/uploads/files/' . $obra['imagen']?>"><?= t('global_download')?></a> |
                    <a href="javascript:window.print();"><?= t('global_print')?></a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Well, all things which I want to print are ok, but when I arrive to this part of the code:

```
<? if (isset($obra['username'])): ?>
    <p><?= t('global_company') ?>: <?php= echo $obra['username'] ?></p>
<? endif; ?>
```

It's when I have the problem because I can see the left side of what I want to see which is the content of `<?= t('global_company') ?>` and what it is on the right side I can't see it. If I remove the `=` then I have an error, so what I'm doing bad.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what does the `t(...)` function do ?

Comment: just try `<?php echo t('global_company') . ':' . $obra['username'] ?>`

Comment: <?=t('global_company') ?>: <?=$obra['username'] ?>

Comment: This might seem like a nit pick, probably is to be fair. naming functions like t() might speed up your coding but will do you no favours in the long run. the generally accepted format is function_name(). That way when you come back to the code in a week, month, years from now you will be able to see what a function does at a glance.

Comment: for instance, format_text() its clear what it does so you dont need to read through its internal code to decipher what your abbreviation meant later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting your code...

```
<p><?= t('global_company') ?>: <?php= echo $obra['username'] ?></p>
```

The second echo isn't valid. You can use `<?=` or `<?php echo` but not `<?php= echo`

Change the line I quoted above to

```
<p><?= t('global_company') ?>: <?= $obra['username'] ?></p>
```

and you should get what you're after

Comment: After do it I have this mistake: 
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: username

Filename: galleries/see.php

Line Number: 33

Comment: Have you looked at what is in `$obra['username']`? Try `var_dump($obra['username'])` to see what you are trying to echo.

Comment: There was a big NULL. Solved now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no delimiter `<?php=`.

`<?php ... ?>`: Inside these tags you have executable php code. If you want to output something you have to do that by using e.g. `echo`.

Example: `<?php echo "Hello"; ?>` prints out `Hello`

`<?= ... ?>` Inside these tags you have a php variable or statement. The return value of a function or the value of a variable is automatically printed out.

Example: `<?= time(); ?>` prints out the return value of `time()` function which is the current time in unix timestamp format.

In your code you could use `<?= $obra['username'] ?>` or `<?php echo $obra['username'] ?>` but **not** `<?= $obra['username'] ?>` as this is not valid php.